# 11 speed shifter levers on my 10 speed drivetrain

Tags: shifting

Currently my Ultegra 6700 (10speed) shifters won’t shift anymore and I planned to buy a new shifter lever.

I’m planning to replace it with Shimano 105 11s shifter on my 10speed cogs and rd . Is it Okay to replace it with 11speed shifters on my 10speed bike???

Thank you for ur answers.

Comment: Google 'pull ratio adaptor'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, won’t work.

Edit: To be more precise: The indexing will be off. The 11 speed road shifters pull more cable for each gear step (each “*click*”). So you’ll have shifted through the whole 10 speed cassette after 8 or 9 clicks. You won’t be able to shift to certain gears reliably, there will be lots of noise and ghost shifting. Similar to badly adjusted cable tension or a bent derailleur hanger. A 11 speed rear derailleur also won’t solve it since the sprocket spacing is different (they didn’t just add an 11th sprocket).

11 speed road shifters have a different pull ratio than 10 speed (except for the Tiagra 4700 10 speed).

I suggest you try to find a Ultegra 6700 or 105 5700 replacement or change the whole drivetrain to 11 speed.

Edit: When changing to 11 speed in the rear you can probably keep the 10 speed chainrings, front derailleur and left shifter.

Comment: but it will still shift??

Comment: The 105 11-sp derailleurs won't be that expensive and through the usual Shimano trickle-down effect on a higher technical level that the 6700. The change-rings though will work with the 11-chain. I did a similar upgrade for another reason, to be able to swap 11-s wheelsets between two bikes.

Comment: @Clint: It will shift but the indexing will be off.

Answer (score 6):

No. This will not work. 11 speed shifters will not pull the correct incremental length of cable for the 10 speed derailleur to move the correct distance to index the chain on each sprocket.

Any Shimano 105 or Ultegra 10 speed shifters are compatible. These are not too hard to get hold of (at least that's my experience the USA).

Beware that the current Tiagra 4700 series 10 speed shifters are *not* compatible, as that groupset uses a different derailleur actuation ratio that older Shimano 10 speed groups.

Answer (score 1):

It will indeed work, however you'll never get it to shift perfectly.

I know it will work, as I did something very similar. I had a tiagra 10 speed set up, and without thinking I changed the shifters to 11 speed 105. Only years later after I sold the bike did I realise why the shifting was never quite right.

In short, avoid mixing speeds. If you do, it'll never shift right and will probably put extra wear on the cassette and derailleur.

Comment: Worth also mentioning that the chain size (10/11sp) will make a difference here too. I can't say which would work best. As the first person said - you really ought to make sure your components match.

Comment: When considering replacing only the shifter as the OP is, how does the chain size come into play?

Comment: "the shifting was never quite right"... so it didn't work, surely?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "work" - I could change gear just fine, yet I could never get it totally smooth, which makes sense as the pull is different. I don't recommend this, but if you have no other option you can still ride your bike. I did for years.